# Converting UNIX timestamp to POSIXct in R

Tags: r, datetime-format, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to convert a column from my hadoop data containing UNIX values (integer) to POSIXct format in R. I am using the following code:

```
hadoop$time <- as.POSIXct(hadoop$time, origin="1970-01-01")
```

However, when I use as.POSIXct I get the following error:

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(hadoop$time, origin="1970-01-01") : do not know how to convert 'hadoop$time' to class "POSIXct"
```

A sample of my column time values is this:

```
integer64
    [1] 1606851081 1606851075 1606851065 1606850993 1606850976 1606823547
```

If I put one of these values through the Epoch date converter it returns a valid date time. I have tried multiple solutions posted on here such as using the "as_datetime" function or the "anytime" package. Sample code:

```
hadoop$time <- anytime(hadoop$time)
hadoop$time <- as_datetime(hadoop$time)
```

However these attempts have also been unsuccessful. Not sure what I am doing wrong here, hope somebody can help me out.

Some added context: I am running this in a notebook in Databricks.

Comment: Are you using `as.POSIXct(x, origin="1970-01-01")` or really `as.POSIXct.default(x, origin="1970-01-01")`? Generally you should ask _reproducible_ questions on Stack Overflow, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038

Comment: Hi @jay.sf, thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my question accordingly. Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: I'm sure you overlooked the reproducible data section in the link. Just provide your integer64 vector using `dput`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reproducible code so the answer will not provide working example as well.
Converting UNIX epoch time to POSIXct is just changing its class attribute. Assuming origin 1970-01-01.

Therefore whatever class of UNIX epoch you have, just coerce it to numeric, and then `as.POSIXct(num, origin="1970-01-01")`.

```r
int64_epoch = bit64::as.integer64(1606851081)
num_epoch = as.numeric(int64_epoch)
as.POSIXct(num_epoch, origin="1970-01-01")
#[1] "2020-12-01 21:31:21 EET"
```